# How do I take an unknown number of elements from a session array in php and use them as separate variables in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays

I a webpage written in php/html that adds the contents of a text box to a session array each time a submit button is pressed. What I need to be able to do is take the unknown number of elements in the session array and have access to each of them in the javascript portion of my code.

Here is the php portion of my code so far:

```
<?php
  session_start();

  if(!isset($_SESSION['answers']))
    $_SESSION['answers'] = array();
?>

<?php
 if (!empty($_POST['submit'])) {
  unset($_POST['submit']);
  $_SESSION['locations'][] = $_POST;
 }

 if (!empty($_POST['display'])){
  foreach ($_SESSION['locations'] as $array){
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('{$array['lat']}')</script>";
 }
}
?>
```

This will display each as an alert, but I need them as variables that can be accessed in javascript.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Just encode your data as JSON. It will be parsed as JavaScript array/object literal by the browser:

```
var locations = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['locations']) ?>;
```

Having a variable for each element of the array is not a good solution.

Comment: Thank you, I am relatively unfamiliar with JSON though. How would I access the specific elements of the newly created JSON object?

Comment: As I said, the generated code will be parsed array or object literal (because JSON can interpertreted as such). In JavaScript you access arrays with bracket notation, like `arr[0]`, `arr[1`], ... `arr[i]` and objects usually with dot notation, `obj.propertyName`, but you can also use bracket notation, `obj['propertyName']`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json.

Comment: When I use the following var loc = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['locations']) ?>;
alert(loc[0]); in the javascript portion of my code, it breaks the code.

Comment: @Ryan: Then you must be doing something wrong. Maybe you are not including those lines correctly.